# Free Form issue with this form has expired

Tags: solspace-freeform

I hope Free form gets this fixed quick. My issue is that the forms did work then they just stopped. We did no upgrades to any of the modules or applications. Running Freeform 4.2 and EE 2.9. All the forms are not working now. Any help would be ideal!

Comment: Well dude, your issue sounds like it has nothing to do with FreeForm (think about it). Just woke up, I'll try and help you in a bit.

Comment: Are channel {exp:channel:form} or {exp:member:login_form} presenting this issue as well?